# Tamanho do form diferente do programado

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei um form, com size 300;300, nele um botao com o seguinte código: `MessageBox.Show(this.Size.ToString());`

Os forms estão ficando muito grandes para minha tela, para que em execução possam ficar legíveis.

Porque o tamanho do form é alterado quando em execução?
Teria como contornar esta situação?

[image: print]

Comment: Como está a propriedade AutoScaleMode ?

Comment: Estava como Font, não havia mexido nessa propriedade.. valeu muito obrigado

Comment: Resolveu ? rsrs

Comment: sim, mudei para None, estou testando o funcionamento:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: postei como uma resposta para vc marcar a questão como resolvida =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique a propriedade AutoScaleMode do Form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx